# Is there ANY way to automatically save the attachments in Thunderbird 78?

Tags: thunderbird, automation, attachments

No extension seems to work with v78, be it FintaQuilla or anything else.

Is there some way / some other way to get attachments on incoming email saved somewhere in automatic manner?

Including even extracting them from Thunderbird database?